# How do I access the class objects to display the total price in PHP?

Tags: php

Question: analytics2.php also obtains an indexed array of Customer objects from CustomerDAO by calling
getCustomerList().
Process the indexed array of Customer objects to identify the customer who spent the most money. For
“bob” (shown in the memory state diagram above), he purchased 5 apples at 5 dollars each (subtotal: 25
dollars) and 2 bananas at 10 dollars each (subtotal: 20 dollars). He spent a total of 45 dollars.

The below is analytics2.php that I have tried to code but I do not know how to proceed further to get the total price for each customer:

```
require_once 'CustomerDAO.php';

$dao = new CustomerDAO();
$customer_list = $dao->getCustomerList();

// YOUR CODE GOES HERE
$subtotal = 0;
$total = 0;
$mostSpent = 0;
$customerList = [];

foreach($customer_list as $customerObj){
    
    $customerName = $customerObj->getName();
    $order_list = $customerObj->getOrderList();
    // var_dump($order_list);

    foreach($order_list as $orderObj){
        
        $qty = $orderObj->getQuantity();
        $price = $orderObj->getItem()->getPrice();
        

        if(sizeof($order_list) > 1){
            
            for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($order_list); $i++){
                $subtotalList = [];
                $subtotal = $qty * $price;
                $subtotalList[] = $subtotal;
            }
           
            
        }
        else{
            $subtotal = $qty * $price;

            
        }
       

        // var_dump($qty);
    }


    

}
echo "The customer who spent the most money is ... (... dollars)";

###
```

This is the CustomerDAO.php:

```
<?php

// DO NOT MODIFY THE CODE BELOW

class CustomerDAO{

    private $customerList;

    # Constructor
    # Simulates retrieval from a database
    public function __construct(){
        
        # Items
        $apple = new Item("apple",5);
        $banana = new Item("banana",10);
        $orange = new Item("orange",15);

        # Orders
        $order1 = new Order($apple,5);
        $order2 = new Order($banana,2);
        $order3 = new Order($apple,10);
        $order4 = new Order($apple,1000);

        $orderList1 = [$order2, $order1];
        $orderList2 = [$order4];
        $orderList3 = [$order1, $order2, $order3];
        
        # Customers
        $bob = new Customer("bob", $orderList1);
        $jane = new Customer("jane", $orderList2);
        $jill = new Customer("jill", $orderList3); 

        $this->customerList = [$bob, $jane, $jill];
    }

    # Get a list of customers 
    # Input: Nothing
    # Output: A list of Customer objects
    public function getCustomerList(){
        return $this->customerList;
    }
}   ?>
```

The expected output should be this:
[image]

Comment: Why 2 nested loop on the same array? `foreach($order_list`, then `for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($order_list); $i++){`?

Comment: @Syscall because i am trying to drill down to access the class objects in a class object to display total as of now i can only get the subtotal